# using monadic IO with lambda expression to read floating point numbers

Tags: haskell

when i try to enter Float numbers this is what i get 
error message "Exception : Prelude.read: no parse"
here is a code...

```
add2Nums = putStrLn " Enter number 1 " >> getLine >>= \a ->
        putStrLn " Enter number 2" >> getLine >>= 
        \b -> putStrLn (show((read a) + (read b)))
```

Comment: so how to you read floating point numbers in a correct way?

Comment: You click on the link to the earlier question and read the answers. If you still don't understand after that, post a new question with  more details about your difficulty understanding them.

Comment: bro i  tried to figuire out how i can do it looking at your answer from earlier question but still i am lost , because in my code i used monadic IO action so i dont know how i can read float numbers without using "read"

Comment: The type signatures you added are useless. You're telling it that you want to read something that's readable and a number. There are a lot of things that are readable and a number (for example, `Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, Word, Word8, Word16, Word32, Word64, Integer, Natural, Float, Double, Rational, Complex Float, Complex Double`). You need to tell it *exactly* which type you want so it can know how to parse it.

Comment: As for `read` in general, it's generally a bad idea. At the very least, you should import `Text.Read` and use `readMaybe` or `readEither`, which let you handle parse errors. For many purposes, it's better to use a proper parsing library.

Comment: ok i understand you now...as you are saying i should specify what exactly type i want to use...its just that i wanted to test if it can work  in a polymorphic way

Comment: Whenever you're parsing something, you have to decide *somewhere* how you're going to parse it. Exactly where and how that decision needs to be made depends on the parsing framework. The same holds whenever you're dealing with polymorphic things; the exact types need to be resolved by the time concrete operations happen. That's a little vague because polymorphic recursion is possible, but in most cases the exact types are resolved at compile time.

Comment: ok thanks so mch
i rely  appreciate your help..!!